# Cassandra - Saving data from wearables from multiple users

Tags: database-design, cassandra, time-series, database, nosql

We need to store data from wearables (think Fitbit) for lots of users for caching. The data will have a resolution of a minute, and we're currently concerned with six variables. After some research we decided to use Cassandra.
The database should be scalable and the amount of variables might increase. There will be only one type of query: get all variables for ownerId between datetime and datetime.
We thought of multiple solutions for this issue:

The first is to make the primary key consist of the ownerId combined with a date (or maybe a month or year) and having the variables combined with time (and maybe day and month) as other column keys.

```
| Primary key        | variable1:hh:MM | variable2:hh:MM | ... |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----|
| ownerId + yy-mm-dd | value           | value           | ... |
| ownerId + yy-mm-dd | value           | value           | ... |
| ...                | ...             | ...             |     |
```

This would result in about in a reasonable amount of columns and would make it easy to add variables and well-scalable. However, this would also mean that everything exists in one column family.

The second option is to make a column family per ownerId:

```
| Primary key | variable1:hh:MM | variable2:hh:MM | ... |
|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----|
| yy-mm-dd    | value           | value           | ... |
| yy-mm-dd    | value           | value           | ... |
| ...         | ...             | ...             |     |
```

This would mean, however, that there will be thousands or millions of column families.

The third option is to make a column family per variable:

```
| Primary key        | hh:MM | hh:MM | ... |
|--------------------|-------|-------|-----|
| ownerId + yy-mm-dd | value | value | ... |
| ownerId + yy-mm-dd | value | value | ... |
| ...                | ...   | ...   |     |
```

This would make it extremely easy to add new variables, but since our query will always require all variables, it would require looking up the data six or more times.

Did we miss any options? Which do you think suit our goals best?

Comment: This is a classic use case for a time-series database which could handle it very efficiently with range queries and two series tags: owner_id and variable name. Have you thought about using a TSDB specifically for storing this data whereas keeping the rest of the schema in Cassandra?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are required to use Cassandra, so we can't use a TSDB for this situation.